# How can I put the elements in a list into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list:

```
txtlst = [
    ['000001', 'DOE', 'JOHN', 'COMSCI', '', 'MATH', '', 'ENGLISH\n'],
    ['000002', 'DOE', 'JANE', 'FRENCH', '', 'MUSIC', '', 'COMSCI\n']
]
```

And I want to put the elements in a dictionary so it looks likes this

```
mydict = {
    '000001': ['000001', 'DOE', 'JOHN', 'COMSCI', '', 'MATH', '', 'ENGLISH\n'],
    '000002': ['000002', 'DOE', 'JANE', 'FRENCH', '', 'MUSIC', '', 'COMSCI\n']
}
```

My problem here is, after I ran the code

```
for i in txtlst:
    key = i[0]  
    value = i
    mydict = {key:value}
```

The two sublists of `txtlst` are added to different dictionaries. How can I fix my code so they will be in the same dictionary as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create a new dictionary with the first element of each list as key:

```
mydict = { i[0]: i for i in txtlst }
```

---

If you wish to do that in a loop like in your approach, you need to initialize a dictionary beforehand and update it in each iteration:

```
mydict = {}
for i in txtlst:
    key = i[0]  
    value = i
    mydict[key] = value
```